# How to open readonly markdown preview in vscode extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, markdown, vscode-extensions, readonly

I'm making a vscode extension and when the user will click on a button, I need a markdown preview to open with specific content.

Right now I'm using this :

```js
let moreInfo = vscode.commands.registerCommand('moreInformation', () => {
        const uri = vscode.Uri.file(context.asAbsolutePath('./resources/info.md'));
        vscode.commands.executeCommand("markdown.showPreview", uri);
    });
```

This does the job but when you double click on the preview, it actually opens the source markdown code and allows the user to modify it. Is there a way to open a markdown preview with read-only mode ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No great solution for this I am afraid.  There is a setting that controls double-clicking the markdown preview and having its associated file opened:

```
Markdown > Preview: Double Click To Switch To Editor
```

The default is enabled, so you would have to disable that in your extension and you probably don't want to do that to your users.

The other alternative I can think of is to detect that the markdown raw editor has been opened and set that to read-only.

```js
vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(async ed => {
    // if (ed.document.fileName === 'the markdown file to lock') {then do below}
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.files.setActiveEditorReadonlyInSession');
});
```

That does work - it will still open the raw markdown file but it will be set to read-only.  But the user could defeat that too but toggling off read-only mode on that file.

So there is currently no good solution for your issue.